# trigger: moving date from 1 table to another

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

here is my code:

```
create trigger term_ost after update on `payments`
for each row
begin
UPDATE `current` s 
INNER JOIN payments w ON w.id_thing = s.id_thing
INNER JOIN payments w ON w.id= s.id
SET s.`new_pay_date` = w.date;
end;
$$
```

It's not working.

I want it to set new date after there is new payment for thing which someone bought and change the last date that was in the field date with the new one from new_pay_date.

@EDIT

I am trying to change my trigger so it will update field "new_pay_date" from current after field date is insterted into payments.

Table current:

```
curr_cash
new_pay_date
id_person
id_thing
sum_of_things
```

Summary:
When I add new data to payments (e.x. someone paid for thing), I want ot update his last payment time in table current. In "sum_of_things" it sums all the money the client paied.

@edit
After this code:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER term_ost AFTER INSERT ON `payments`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE `current`
        SET s.`new_pay_date` = NEW.date
    WHERE 
        s.id_thing = NEW.id
END;
```

there is error:

```
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`payments` (
`id` ,
`date` ,
`id_thing` ,
`thing_cost`
)
VALUES (
'12312312322', '2012-12-11 15:00:00', '1', '500'
)

MySQL comment:
#1054 - Unknown column 's.new_pay_date' in 'field list'
```

... :-(

Comment: Maybe it's because of double join definition with "payments w". Try `INNER JOIN payments w ON w.id_thing = s.id_thing AND w.id = s.id_thing`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same table alias `w` multiple times and that is not allowed. Seems you want to join on multiple columns:

```
CREATE TRIGGER term_ost AFTER INSERT ON `payments`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE `current`
        SET `new_pay_date` = NEW.date
    WHERE 
        id_thing = NEW.id
END;
```

Comment: yes, okey. But I changed it a little bit, and I need to update the table current after inster into payments. Not update. When I change "update on`payments` to inster on payments. I get error that there is no column name new_pay_date in payments. Because there isn't, it's in current which I want to change.

Comment: Can you update your trigger definition in the question, and also brief on the structure of `current` table?

Comment: Please see the updated response. You need to refer to the `NEW` table that contains the record that was inserted. Also, you don't need to JOIN, simply use the date and id from the `NEW` table to identify the records in `current` that should be updated.

Comment: It didn't work. By the way, id_thing is id of an item, and id itself is id of person. So I cannot compare them. Changed it to NEW.id_thing, but still no hope.

Comment: Oops, there is no `s` alias, my bad! I corrected the trigger definition.

Comment: Still giving the same error when I enter data:
#1054 - Unknown column 'new_pay_date' in 'field list'. I think this trigger tries to update current? (there is new_pay_date) Really.. I am so lost with this.